# Refreshing the UI

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  dayRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
  dayRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

  layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
  dayRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

  dayRecyclerViewAdapter = new DayRecyclerViewAdapter(DataUtility.getRecords());
  dayRecyclerView.setAdapter(dayRecyclerViewAdapter);
}
```

The code above is the MainActivity of the app. The app when launch shows a `RecyclerView`, based on the `ArrayList` of data got from the method `DataUtility.getRecords()`. The data may update from time to time. Whenever I switch the app from background back to foreground, the UI will refresh.

The implementation works fine in `Android 4.3-5.0`. However, when i deploy the app to Android 7.0. I found that the UI do not know refreshing, unless I quit the app and launch again.

What's the problem here? How can I force the app to refresh whenever I switch the app from background to foreground?

** Update:

I have tried to add the method onResume()

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    dayRecyclerViewAdapter.setDataSet(DataUtility.getRecords());
    dayRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have checked DataUtility.getRecords() can print out all the latest records. But it does not reflect on the UI.

Comment: implementing notifydatachanged method for adapter may works

Comment: How you refresh app right now ? I do not see any life cycle method implementation other than `onCreate()` ?

Answer (score 3):

On Android 4.3 to 5, your activity is being destroyed, and then recreated. Hence, it reflects the database changes when you come back.

On Android 7, the changes don't show up because you are probably testing on a phone with sufficient ram to keep the system from destroying  the activity. Therefore, the `onCreate` method does not get called.

**Solution:**
Check for database changes in `onResume` method, and if there are changes, notify the adapter accordingly after updating the data in your adapter.

Comment: Do you mean calling things like adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the onResume() method?

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged will not check your database for updates. You need to either do it manually in onResume (minimal code changes) or use Room with LiveData (recommended).

Comment: I have manually checked the database and then updated the ArrayList, and set the data again to the adapter. However, it does not refresh.... :(

Comment: Did you make the changes and shifted the code to `onResume`? If so, please share that code.

Comment: Updated my question above... :(

Comment: There is no special for the adapter code. the method just assign the ArrayList to the private ArrayList stored in the adapter. That's all. The adapter has implemented methods like onCreateViewHolder and on BindViewHolder. All works well except that it cannot refresh itself.

Comment: I can't reproduce your app's behaviour so it has to be something in the code you have not shared. So, without added code, there is no point in guessing randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a problem with Recycler view's adapter updation. Try calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when the data changes. This will refresh your recycler view and the list will get updated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go for android architecture components using LiveData

LiveData is an observable data holder class. Unlike a regular observable, LiveData is lifecycle-aware, meaning it respects the lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, fragments, or services. This awareness ensures LiveData only updates app component observers that are in an active lifecycle state.

You can follow the link for more details

https://medium.com/google-developers/lifecycle-aware-data-loading-with-android-architecture-components-f95484159de4

Following the code snippet to show how to observe the live data

```
public class NameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NameViewModel mModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Other code to setup the activity...

        // Get the ViewModel.
        mModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NameViewModel.class);

        // Create the observer which updates the UI.
        final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
                // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
                mNameTextView.setText(newName);
            }
        };

        // Observe the LiveData, passing in this activity as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
        mModel.getCurrentName().observe(this, nameObserver);
    }
}
```